# How to pass basic auth and viper config value in golang Test cases

Tags: go

I am creating test case using echo and testify/assert,I am not able to get viper string token which is passed into main package, I am calling main package service file.

```
func TestGetData(t *testing.T) {
    // Setup
    e := echo.New()
    req := httptest.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, "/api/v1/testdata", nil)
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    log.Info(viper.GetString("token"))
    req.Header.Add("token", viper.GetString("token"))
    rec := httptest.NewRecorder()
    c := e.NewContext(req, rec)
    res := rec.Result()
    defer res.Body.Close()

    // Assertions
    if assert.NoError(t, controllers.GetData(c)) {
        assert.Equal(t, http.StatusOK, rec.Code)
        //assert.Equal(t, sections, rec.Body.String())
    }
}
```

when i ran "go run main.go" its printing token but when i testing using "go test", Its displaying none.

Second question is - how to pass basic auth username and pass into main_test.go file

Comment: please confirm that your facing issue in this line: `  log.Info(viper.GetString("token"))`

Comment: i am facing issue on req.Header.Add("token", viper.GetString("token")), I just need to pass token and base64 with in golang test method

Answer (score 0):

To set basic auth try this:

```
req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Basic "+basicAuth(username, password))

func basicAuth(username, password string) string {
    auth := username + ":" + password
    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(auth))
}
```

Also replace your **httptest**.NewRequest with **http**.NewRequest as mentioned below:

```
    req := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, "/api/v1/testdata", nil)
```

Ensure that you are putting the value in the get api something like: `viper.SetDefault("token", "12334")`

To check that your keys is in viper or not run: `require.Equal(t, viper.AllSettings(), "teststring")`

If you are still facing the issue, share the github url with a sample app code.

Comment: Thanks prakash, I am asking about in unit testing, You are posting about normal http request.